# Android Multiline Toolbar Title

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I have a Toolbar that when in landscape mode isn't as wide as usual, but it has more height than usual and for that reason I want to set the title to be multiline (2 lines to be precise) when it is in landscape. I have tried some things where I put a TextView inside of the Toolbar, but when I try to access the TextView to set it's title (since the the title is variable) I get a NullPointer after using findViewById.

Here is some code of the current situation (without multiline):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = (int)( size.x * 0.37);
        int height =  Math.round(size.x * 0.63f * 0.25f);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    if (executeOnResume) {
        currentProject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Project");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("This is a pretty long piece of text, I hope it fits");
        // A lot of irrelevant code...
        //...
        //...
    } else { loadStuff();}
}
```

And here is the toolbar xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:title="@string/menuLabel1a"
        app:layout_widthPercent="37%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="26%"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarTitleText"
        android:background="@color/greyLight"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/double_height_toolbar"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarTitleText"
    android:background="@color/greyLight"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:title="@string/menuLabel1a"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_normal"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            android:maxLines="2" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Other Solution is for ActionBar**

The default TextView of the ActionBar does not support line wrapping, and there is no exposed method to set it to wrap. So you can create a flexible layout, like this: **action_bar_title_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then set this as the custom layout on your ActionBar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_title_layout);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title)).setText(
    "This is a long text title that will wrap to multiple lines, when necessary.");
```

Comment: I don't really have an explicit subtitle, but just a title that is very long. Setting a subtitle would involve using 2 different strings (1 for the title, 1 for the subtitle), but I only have one String, so I don't see how this really helps.

Comment: If I would use the updated answer, would I set the title the same way or would I have to do it in a different way?

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal remove this line in your toolbar `android:title="@string/menuLabel1a"` and add it in `TextView`. it solve your problem.

Comment: That is just a tempory title, I set the title programmatically in the onResume in my Activity class like `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("This is a pretty long piece of text, I hope it fits");
        `.

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal I have posted other solution too try it.

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution who was work for me :

```
fun Toolbar.disableTitleSingleLine() {
    for (i in 0..childCount) {
        val child = getChildAt(i)
        if (child is TextView) {
            child.isSingleLine = false
        }
    }
}
```

According `Toolbar` implementation, the title `TextView` is created when text been set.
It's important to call this extension after title set.