# Text won't start at top with gravity=top

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-toolbar

I've been trying to set the title of my toolbar to start at the top of the toolbar, but while the I have set `android:gravity="top"` the text still start at the center (vertical) of the toolbar. I think this could have something to do with using a custom layout for the toolbar, but I use it because I need it, so I hope someone knows a way to set the text to start at the top.

Here is layout my toolbar is in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutProjectOverview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:title="@string/menuLabel1a"
            app:layout_widthPercent="37%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="26%"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarTitleText"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_basic"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutObjectNav"
            app:layout_widthPercent="63%"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="400%"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toolbar2"
            android:background="@drawable/border_basic">

            <!-- Some irrelevant xml code -->

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutObjectNav">

            <!-- Some more irrelevant xml code -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <!-- Some more irrelevant xml code -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the custom toolbar layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code where I set the custom layout (and some other stuff):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    currentProject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Project");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.layout_toolbar);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title)).setText(currentProject.getTitle());
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = (int)( size.x * 0.37);
        int height =  Math.round(size.x * 0.63f * 0.25f);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(currentProject.getTitle());
    }
    // Some irrelevant java code
}
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here is the TextAppearance Style I use for the toolbar:

```
<style name="toolbarTitleText">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">3</item>
</style>
```

Comment: With the size of the toolbar, the textsize of the textview and the padding in the toolbar, is there any room left for the textview to reposition itself?

Comment: I would think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: Did you override your gravity in your style here: app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarTitleText" ?

Comment: @BHuelse No, I didn't. Also I have just added the style to the question

Answer (score 0):

add a textView in your toolbar

like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: This was not what I was searching for, also I have tried this before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479043/android-multiline-toolbar-title

Comment: so please add pic let me know what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following :

1- Disable the title by using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

2- Add a textView under your `toolbar` as your toolbar title :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I've tried that before, but it didn't really work, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479043/android-multiline-toolbar-title